# Error while installing jenkins

Tags: jenkins, installation

I keep getting this error when I try installing jenkins

```
Error: File contains no section headers. 
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo, line: 1 
'--2015-05-19 13:54:44--  http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is there any extra spaces.

Here is link to the same issue which he solved by removing extra spaces.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=50394#p214016

Comment: Thankyou:) Error got resolved. It was because of the extra space in the repo file